# Deploy snapshots and releases via Maven commandline

Tags: maven, deployment, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

I want to deploy projects inside my CI/CD pipeline without using the distributionManagement block inside my pom which would look like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>x-releases</name>
        <url>http://serverhostname/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>x-snapshots</name>
        <url>serverhostname/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I tried specifying the repositories via command line:

```
-DaltSnapshotDeploymentRepository=myserver::default::serverhostname/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local \
-DaltReleaseDeploymentRepository=myserver::default::serverhostname/artifactory/artifactory/libs-release-loca
```

But it fails with

```
Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter
```

Specifying -DaltDeploymentRepository allows me to deploy an artifact to a repository, but I am not sure how to distringuish between SNAPSHOT and RELEASE anymore. I thought maven would be able to do this somehow automatically.

What commandline options to use to replace this distributionManagement block?

Comment: Why won't you like to use distributionManagement?

Comment: My first thought was: I would like to keep the details of deploying the project seperated from the project itself. I thought those are part of the CI pipeline and not part of the project. But I know, this is kind of a idealistic approach.

The second reason is, that the project it autogenerated using openapi-codegen. It generates a whole project, including a pom. But without the dostributionmanagement block. I would have to script it being patched into it in the CI pipeline, which is kind of ugly. :(

Comment: Are those generated pom's using a parent?

Comment: No, openapi-codegent does not generate a pom referencing a parent.

Answer (score 1):

Check your maven-deploy-plugin version.

I was using version 2.7 and getting the same error but upgraded to 2.8.2 and the build completed successfully.

Here's the dependency:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Why did you use the `maven-deploy-plugin` without any configuration?